# How to trigger a function when cursor stops moving for 3 seconds using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am just exploring hooks but I don't know what logic I have to use in order to trigger a function after cursor stopped moving for 3 seconds

My try

```
const handleMouseMove = () => {
        console.log('I don't know what to do ???')

    };
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        };
    },[]);
```

Comment: setInterval on the component mount to check last_mouse_move_time and current_mouse_move_time ,if diff is >=3 sec then call a function  ,on mouse_move update the current_mouse_move_time,clear interval on componentWillUnmout

Answer (score 1):

```
let timer = null;

const handleMouseMove = () => {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // do your things...
  }, 3000);
};
```

Append:

in your `useEffect callback`, you should clear this `timer` to avoid timeout callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  };
},[]);
```

Comment: I think `clearTimeout()` is safe to call on null, so you might not need the if guard.

Answer (score 1):

as said in the comment following is my try, hope it will work for you

```
function  MouseTracker (props) {
    const [lastMoveTime, setLastMoveTime] = useState(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    const [curMoveTime, setCurMoveTime] = useState(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

   function handleMouseMove(event){
     setLastMoveTime(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
   }
   const timeTrack=setInterval(function(){
    let curMoveTime=new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    if(curMoveTime-lastMoveTime >= 3){
        //trigger the function call
    }else{
        //or updat the curmove time
        setCurMoveTime(curMoveTime)
    }
},100)
//
return <YourComponentCode/>
}
```